# How to keep organized Web Sites for Inspiration

Tags: resource-recommendations

I usually find inspiration from many CSS Galleries, But I don't have an idea of how I can keep organized all those nice creations for inspiration. I've tried to make some bookmarks in Chrome but I don't like this idea much. I'd prefer to have atleast a small thumbnail for a fast preview.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but I think this would be more on-topic at [Super User](http://superuser.com) (if you seek for chrome related or standalone app) or [Web Applications SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) (if you seek for a web service). Moreover, there's already *similar* Q&A on Webapps.se: [Any good alternatives to delicious?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10409/7276) Though it doesn't take your thumbnail-requirement into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a social bookmarking site like [delicious.com](http://www.delicious.com/). You don't get the thumbnails (which would go out of date anyway) but you can tag your bookmarks with keywords, making it quite a powerful, searchable resource.